# how to solve this, the IFCONFIG command can't be opened, and when I want to reinstall it also doesn't work, is there a solution?

Tags: boot, networking, server, nvidia, ifconfig

[The link below explains the problem I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6pIT.png)

Comment: Have you *read* the output you get? If not: please do read it. It says *exactly* what you should try. In addition, ifconfig has been depreceated for ten-fifteen years. Use `ip`.

Comment: Do you have any non-default repositories in your software sources?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ip all`
It will show you detailed network config with the all NIC cards with mac and IP addresses